# Having problems with ***Applications Menu***

Tags: appmenu

I'm having a problem with ***applications menu*** (Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS). My applications are combined in different sections. Such as Calculator, Backup, character, Fonts, Document Viewer etc in **Utilities** folder. So when I click on **Utilities** folder and don't pick any application (to use) & click outside the box to cancel, it gets stuck and I have to restart my PC in order to use my PC again. Please help me out & thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your Ubuntu version.

Comment: This is indeed not expected behavior. Mention the Ubuntu version that you use, because that will matter here. It may also be useful to mention details on the graphical card in your system. Use "edit" to add that information to your question.